# Snakemake rule issue with bcftools view filtering

Tags: snp, snakemake, bcftools

I am creating a bioinformatics pipeline using Snakemake doing everying from adapter trimming of raw sequencing data in .fq to mapping, SNP calling and SNP filtering.

The issue i am having is when i try to filter specific chromosomes of the bcf files, using the --regions. The rule i have created below works and does create a filtered bcf file.

```
rule bcftools_filter:
    input:
        bcf = "/dir/{sample}_aligned_call.bcf",
    output:
        "/dir/{sample}_aligned_call_filter.bcf"
    threads: 20
    shell:
        "bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 -v snps {input.bcf} -o {output}"
```

However i would like to add the --regions parameter to the bcftools command. I have tried the shell part of the rule to several things

```
bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 -v snps {input.bcf} --regions <chr1,chr2> -o {output}
bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 -v snps {input.bcf} --regions {chr1,chr2} -o {output}
bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 -v snps {input.bcf} --regions {{chr1,chr2}} -o {output}
bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 -v snps {input.bcf} --regions {{chr1} {chr2}} 
 {{chr2}} -o {output}
bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 -v snps {input.bcf} --regions ['chr1','chr2'] -o {output}
```

But it doesn't work, and i am having trouble finding any suggestions to this specific issue.

I know it works if i just run bcftools filter in my command line, so using --regions should work.

Could anyone have any suggestions how to add --regions to the snakemake rule?

Comment: Have you tried `expand()` function? https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=expand#the-expand-function

Comment: No i havent tried that, i didn't realize you could potentially use the expand() function for the shell part. But i will look into it

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work:

```
rule bcftools_filter:
    input:
        bcf = "/dir/{sample}_aligned_call.bcf",
    output:
        "/dir/{sample}_aligned_call_filter.bcf"
    params:
        regions="chr1,chr2"
    threads: 20
    shell:
        "bcftools view -Ob --threads {threads} -m2 -M2 --regions {params.regions} -v snps {input.bcf} -o {output}"
```

You could also include the regions as part of the output file name, rather than specifying it as a param.

Comment: Would a simple `--regions \"chr1,chr2\"` in the shell command not work?

Comment: You don't need to even quote it. However having it as a param allows you to set it elsewhere (e.g., the command line).